# JSON deserialization exception on mobile devices, expected delimiter '' path., without special characters in value, works on desktop

Tags: asp.net, json, model-view-controller, serialization

I'm developing a webshop in ASP.NET MVC, and I handle my cart data with JSON objects.
Upon opening the CartDetails, I try to deserialize my JSON, which works perfectly on desktop, but fails on mobile devices, both iOS Safari and Chrome.

```
{"CartItems":{"cartItems":[{"ID":4648,"ProductCode":"ASZIM02","Quantity":1,"Name":"AKKUKIEGYENLÍTŐ, AKKUSZIMMETRIZÁLÓ 24V/3A#TÖLTÉSKIEGYENLÍTŐ","Price":17099.99}]},"ID":"b6b4ee16-d58a-4b1c-90e2-261decd84af5","TotalCount":1,"TotalPrice":17099.99}
```

And exception says the problem is with line 1, position 95. which is "AKKUKIEG**YE**NLÍTŐ", no special characters at all.

And my problem is, that on desktop, works well. Anyone encountered this before? Is "" character the real problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it an error on the client-side (browser)?

Comment: nope, Newtonsoft's JSON deserializer exception on server side

Comment: Here is an image of the issue:
https://ibb.co/px0pLSf

Comment: Looking at the image, it tries to read the value from the cookies which are stored locally in your browser (desktop vs mobile). Check if you can to see if the cookie has its value stored differently. It may be due to browser implementation on the mobile.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please amend your question to include the exception details.